# Filtering in QFileDialog

Tags: qt, filter, qfiledialog

I would like to filter the files that are shown in a `QFileDialog` more specifically than just by file extensions. The examples I found in the Qt documentation only show filters like `Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg);;Text files (*.txt);;XML files (*.xml)` and such. In addition to this I would also like to specify a filter for files that should *not* show up in the file dialog, e.g. `XML files (*.xml)` but not `Backup XML files (*.backup.xml)`.

So the problem I have is that I would like to show some files in the file dialog that have certain file extension, but I would not like to show other files with a specific file name suffix (and the same file extension).

For example:

Files to show:

```
file1.xml  
file2.xml
```

Files not to show:

```
file1.backup.xml  
file2.backup.xml
```

I would like to ask if it is possible to define filters like these for a `QFileDialog`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe what you can do is:

1. Create a custom proxy model. You can use [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) as a base class for your model;
2. In the proxy model override the [filterAcceptsRow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) method and return false for files which have the *".backup."* word in their names;
3. Set new proxy model to the file dialog: [QFileDialog::setProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setProxyModel);

Below is an example:

Proxy model:

```
class FileFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
protected:
    virtual bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex& source_parent) const;
};

bool FileFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    QFileSystemModel* fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());
    return fileModel->fileName(index0).indexOf(".backup.") < 0;
    // uncomment to call the default implementation
    //return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent);
}
```

dialog was created this way:

```
QFileDialog dialog;
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
dialog.setProxyModel(new FileFilterProxyModel);
dialog.setNameFilter("XML (*.xml)");
dialog.exec();
```

The proxy model is supported by non-native file dialogs only.

Comment: As miile7 noted below, `setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);` must be called before `setProxyModel()`. Tested with Qt 5.11

Answer (score 2):

The solution of @serge_gubenko is working well. Create your own `ProxyModel` by inheriting from the `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

```
class FileFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
protected:
    virtual bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex& source_parent) const;
};

bool FileFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    // Your custom acceptance condition
    return true;
}
```

Just make sure to set `DontUseNativeDialog` **before** setting the Proxy model (*Edit*: @serge_gubenkos answer does that now). Native dialogs do not support custom `ProxyModel`s.

```
QFileDialog dialog;
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
dialog.setProxyModel(new FileFilterProxyModel);
dialog.setNameFilter("XML (*.xml)");
dialog.exec();
```

It took quite some time for me to find this out. This was written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43422158/5934316)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I've used it with **QFileDialog** object. And this only shows me the files listed in the appropriate directory. It is excellent to just choose the files to be processed. For example, an XML file, a PNG image, etcetera.

Here I present my example

```
 OlFileDialog QFileDialog (this); 
 QString slFileName; 
 olFileDialog.setNameFilter (tr ("Files (* xml)")); 
 olFileDialog.setFileMode (QFileDialog :: anyfile); 
 olFileDialog.setViewMode (QFileDialog :: Detail); 
 if (olFileDialog.exec ()) 
     olFileDialog.selectFile (slFileName); 
 else 
     return;
```

The dialog box will display only presents xml files.