# QFileSystemModel hide certain files

Tags: qt, qfilesystemmodel

What I'm looking for is pretty much the opposite of QFileSystemModel::setNameFilters().
I'd like to set filters that catch things I *don't* want to show, but let everything else through. I don't see any way to go through and hide certain files, because remove() actually removes the file from the system.

How do I go about this?

Edit for clarification: I have a specific list of filenames that I don't want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but are there any existing presets in [QDir::Filters](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qdir.html#Filter-enum) that you can use? It will filter things like dirs, symlinks, system files etc

Comment: Oops. Should have been clearer. I have a specific list of filenames I don't want to show.

Comment: Then you need a custom proxy - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893122/filtering-in-qfiledialog

Comment: That looks like it will work. Thanks! If you want to make it a proper answer, I'll accept it.