# Customized QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I want to implement customized file open dialog using Qt. I have following scenario 
I have file with this kind of extension

```
a.txt.1
a.txt.2
a.txt.3

b.txt.1
b.txt.2

c.txt.1
c.txt.4
```

In file Dialog i want to show only file with highest number extension e.g. a.txt.3 , b.txt.2 , c.txt.4 is there any way to add filter in QFileDialog. If you have any suggestion besides from filtering please let me know.

Comment: How do you know which is highest?

Comment: highest number in extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement and set your own proxy model:

void QFileDialog::[setProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setProxyModel)(QAbstractProxyModel * proxyModel)

> Sets the model for the views to the given proxyModel. This is useful
>   if you want to modify the underlying model; for example, to add
>   columns, filter data or add drives.

Comment: as per your suggestion i have implemented and it works Thank you for your helped also this link help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893122/filtering-in-qfiledialog/4893903#4893903