# Regular Expression Filter for QFileDialog

Tags: qt, fileopendialog, qregularexpression

I would like to display a file open dialog that filters on a particular pattern, for example `*.000` to `*.999`.

`QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames` allows you to specify discrete filters, such as `*.000`, `*.001`, etc. I would like to set a regular expression as a filter, in this case `^.*\.\d\d\d$`, i.e. any file name that has a three digit extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ariwez pointed me into the right direction. The main thing to watch out for is to call `dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog)` *before* `dialog.setProxyModel`.

The proxy model is:

```
class FileFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
protected:
    virtual bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex& sourceParent) const
    {
        QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
        QFileSystemModel* fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());

        // I don't want to apply the filter on directories.
        if (fileModel == nullptr || fileModel->isDir(index0))
            return true;

        auto fn = fileModel->fileName(index0);

        QRegExp rx(".*\\.\\d\\d\\d");
        return rx.exactMatch(fn);
    }
};
```

The file dialog is created as follows:

```
QFileDialog dialog;

// Call setOption before setProxyModel.
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
dialog.setProxyModel(new FileFilterProxyModel);
dialog.exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by adding proxy model to QFileDialog. It is explained here: [Filtering in QFileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893122/filtering-in-qfiledialog)

Comment: According to the Qt documentation, this should work. I have followed the instructions in the link above, however, `filterAcceptsRow` of the sub class is never called.

Comment: I should add that I am using Qt 5.4.1, Win 10 and VS 2013.

Comment: Well, with Qt5 and VS dialog.setProxyModel(&filter) is not working - and dialog.proxyModel() remains null so no filtering is being done.