# QFileDialog with proxy model sort by date actually uses alphabetical order of date

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

In PyQt 5.11.2 (on Windows 10), QFileDialog with the DontUseNativeDialog option set has a bug when sorting by the 'Date Modified' column: it does not sort by the actual date - it sorts alphabetically by the non-zero-padded MM-DD-YYYY string, meaning that 9-12-2018 shows up as being more recent than 12-12-2018.
[image]
Is there a workaround or a fix?

The native dialog does sort by date correctly, but, the motivation for using the non-native dialog is that the native dialog does not respect fileDialog.setProxyModel (used to filter out certain files by more complex regex rules), described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893903/3577105) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42083326/3577105), which I think is spelled out / alluded to by this line in the docs:

> By default, a platform-native file dialog will be used if the platform
>   has one. In that case, the widgets which would otherwise be used to
>   construct the dialog will not be instantiated, so related accessors
>   such as layout() and itemDelegate() will return null. You can set the
>   DontUseNativeDialog option to ensure that the widget-based
>   implementation will be used instead of the native dialog.

The code: the dialog is spawned by calling self.load() (no arguments)

```
def load(self,fileName=None):
    if not fileName:
        fileDialog=QFileDialog()
        fileDialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        fileDialog.setProxyModel(CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel(self))
        fileDialog.setNameFilter("CSV Radio Log Data Files (*.csv)")
        fileDialog.setDirectory(self.firstWorkingDir)
        if fileDialog.exec_():
            fileName=fileDialog.selectedFiles()[0]
```

...
 and the entire CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel class which only has one function:

```
# code for CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel partially taken from
#  https://github.com/ZhuangLab/storm-control/blob/master/steve/qtRegexFileDialog.py
class CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
#       print("initializing CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel")
        super(CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel,self).__init__(parent)

    # filterAcceptsRow - return True if row should be included in the model, False otherwise
    #
    # do not list files named *_fleetsync.csv or *_clueLog.csv
    #  do a case-insensitive comparison just in case
    def filterAcceptsRow(self,source_row,source_parent):
#       print("CSV filterAcceptsRow called")
        source_model=self.sourceModel()
        index0=source_model.index(source_row,0,source_parent)
        # Always show directories
        if source_model.isDir(index0):
            return True
        # filter files
        filename=source_model.fileName(index0).lower()
#       filename=self.sourceModel().index(row,0,parent).data().lower()
#       print("testing lowercased filename:"+filename)
        # never show non- .csv files
        if filename.count(".csv")<1:
            return False
        if filename.count("_fleetsync.csv")+filename.count("_cluelog.csv")==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: you could show an image as proof of the bug

Comment: If it was really sorting by date-strings, you would get sequences like 1-1-2018, 2-2-2000, 3-3-2014, 4-4-2002 (note the years). Needless to say, I cannot reproduce such behaviour, so I strongly suspect that you are actually sorting by a different column.

Comment: Understandable skepticism.  Added a picture.

Comment: also added explanation of / motivation for non-native dialog

Comment: @TomGrundy You need to show the code you used to produce that dialog, because it obviously isn't just using the default settings. The screenshot alone doesn't really prove anything.

Comment: added code to original question

Comment: @TomGrundy as I thought the problem is in your proxy that does not take into account the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the custom QSortFilterProxyModel since in the lessThan method the values are strings, the solution is to convert to the appropriate type for the comparison:

```
class CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self,source_row,source_parent):
        source_model = self.sourceModel()
        index0=source_model.index(source_row,0,source_parent)
        if source_model.isDir(index0):
            return True
        filename = source_model.fileName(index0).lower()
        if filename.count(".csv")<1:
            return False
        return filename.count("_fleetsync.csv")+filename.count("_cluelog.csv") == 0

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        source_model = self.sourceModel()

        if left.column() == right.column() == 1: 
            if source_model.isDir(left) and not source_model.isDir(right):
                return True
            return source_model.size(left) < source_model.size(right)

        if left.column() == right.column() == 2:
            return source_model.type(left) < source_model.type(right)

        if left.column() == right.column() == 3:
            return source_model.lastModified(left) < source_model.lastModified(right)
        return super(CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel, self).lessThan(left, right)
```

---

As indicated by [@ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) a simpler option is to overwrite the proxy sort:

```
class CSVFileSortFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self,source_row,source_parent):
        source_model = self.sourceModel()
        index0=source_model.index(source_row,0,source_parent)
        if source_model.isDir(index0):
            return True
        filename = source_model.fileName(index0).lower()
        if filename.count(".csv")<1:
            return False
        return filename.count("_fleetsync.csv")+filename.count("_cluelog.csv") == 0

    def sort(self, column, order):
        self.sourceModel().sort(column, order)
```

Comment: brilliant!  Thanks, that works perfectly.  It's interesting that the default lessThan doesn't account for that when the column name is 'date modified' or such.

Comment: @TomGrundy This is not the proxy problem but the sourcemodel, the sourcemodel is a QFileSystemModel that internally has a proxy but in this case it is not used because it used the Qt::DisplayRole role that returns strings. You have to verify if you add modifications.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is overcomplicated. All you need to do is override `sort` in the proxy and call `self.sourceModel().sort(column, order)`.

Comment: The view will automatically pass the necessary arguments.

Comment: @ekhumoro I already understood you, instead of calling lessthan you must use the sourcemodel sort